# How to remove some value of condition in scss?

Tags: css, for-loop, if-statement, sass

I have a condition in scss, but I want to remove my value, how can I remove that value in scss? I put some code in bellow and also with image too

```
$color-sp: color-sp;
$width: 100%;

@for $i from 1 through 12 {
   @for $j from 12 through 1 {
      .#{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
          width: $j;
      }
  }
}
```

I put some link to know my result :

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3d049565b0be28429f7d3803baf1bcb1

Comment: What do you mean by "remove my value"?

Comment: duplicate value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with an if statement

```
$color-sp: color-sp;
$width: 100%;
$max: 12;
$min: 1;
$j: $max;
@for $i from $min through $max {
    #{$color-sp}-#{$i} {
        width: $j;
    }
    $j : $j - 1;
}
```

Comment: how about 12 looping condition?

Comment: I understood your question as you want to remove the classes where the number in class name and width are the same... if that's the case you can use the same if in the 12 looping condition

Comment: but the result not same as your mine, looping just removed the same value in variable `$i` and `$j` I want make them like the opposite number if you use `color-sp-12` the result is `width = 1`, and if you use `color-sp-11` the result is `width = 2`, and looping end until `color-sp-1` and the result is `width = 12`

Comment: now I understand what you are trying to do, give me a sec I'll figure it out :D

Comment: really? thank you so much you want to help me to solve this problem ;)

Comment: I updated the answer this should solve your problem :D

Comment: Ok, thank you very much bro, this works, but is it okay to use more variables?

Comment: I added more variables so it's easier to edit if needed, I think it's okay having more variables if it helps you maintain the code in the future